# kivy app didnt finish loading

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__name__":
    Myapp().run()
```

Loading stop on:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\admin\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-04-13_14.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
```

where is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do not return a `root` in the [`build()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.build) method, the application does not start, so kivy does not load more components, so the application closes.

**Solution:**

returns a widget.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```